# Prove that the sequence $b_n = 1$, $b_{n+1} = \frac{1}{1+b_n}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I need to prove that the sequence $b_1 = 1$, $b_{n+1} = \frac{1}{1+b_n}$ converges.

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = L$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_{n+1} = L$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_{n+1} = \frac{1}{1+\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n} \implies L = \frac{1}{1+L} \implies L^2 + L - 1 = 0 \implies L = \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

So I know that if the sequence converges to $L$ then $L = \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. How can I prove that the sequence converges?

**EDIT:**

With the help of the answers I got my resolution:

Let's prove that $b_n$ converges by proving that the subsequences $b_{2n}$ and $b_{2n-1}$ are monotonic and bounded.

I want to prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb N$, $b_{2n} < b_{2(n+1)} < L$ and $b_{2n-1} > b_{2(n+1)-1} > L$.

I'm going to prove using induction.

**First Step:**

$\frac{1}{2} < \frac{3}{5} < \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \implies b_2 < b_4 < L $

and

$1> \frac{2}{3} > \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \implies b_1 > b_3 > L $

**Second Step:**

Let's prove that $b_{2n-1} > b_{2n+1} > L \implies b_{2n+1} > b_{2n+3} > L$

and $b_{2n} < b_{2n+2} < L \implies b_{2n+2} < b_{2n+4} < L$

$b_{2n-1}>b_{2n+1}>L \implies 1+b_{2n-1} > 1+b_{2n+1}>1+L \implies$

$\frac{1}{1+b_{2n-1}} = b_{2n} < \frac{1}{1+b_{2n+1}} = b_{2n+2} < \frac{1}{1+L} = L \implies $

$1+b_{2n} < 1+b_{2n+2}<1+L \implies \frac{1}{1+b_{2n}} = b_{2n +1} > \frac{1}{1+b_{2n+2}} = b_{2n+3} > \frac{1}{1+L} = L \implies$

$1+b_{2n+1} > 1+b_{2n+3} > 1+L \implies \frac{1}{1+b_{2n+1}} = b_{2n +2} < \frac{1}{1+b_{2n+3}} = b_{2n+4} < \frac{1}{1+L} = L$.

Thus $b_n$ converges.

Comment: To be completely rigorous, the only thing you've proven that the two subsequences converge, but not what they converge to. This can be quickly remedied by seeing that both subsequences satisfy the new relation: $a_{n+2} = \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+a_{n}}}$, which gives the same limit $L$ as the original computation you showed above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try showing that the subsequences of even and odd terms are monotonic and bounded. If this is the case, then both subsequences must converge. From there it shouldn't be too hard to show that they converge to the same thing, and therefore the overall sequence must converge.

Comment: How did you know that the even and odd subsequences are monotonic and bounded? Did you write out the terms and saw the pattern?

Comment: @Sorfosh All simple continued fractions have that property.

Comment: @TrevorGunn I see, is that a rule of thumb or a mathematical theorem? Thanks.

Comment: @Sorfosh See [Theorem 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems) and its corollaries.

Comment: @Sorfosh Or: $\,\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} = \dfrac{b_{n-1}+1}{b_n+1}\,$, so the ratios of consecutive terms alternate between $\lt 1$ and $\gt 1$.

Comment: Thanks guys! That helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another interesting way of proving its convergence (And might provide some nice insights into the limit): Define
$$b_n=\frac{h_n}{g_n}$$

where these are the numerator and denominator of $b_n$ (with no reductions to a simpler form after appyling the recursion formula). Then from your definition
$$b_{n+1}=\frac{h_{n+1}}{g_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{h_n}{g_n}}=\frac{g_n}{h_n+g_n}.$$

Hence,
$$h_{n+1}=g_n$$
and
$$g_{n+1}=h_n+g_n.$$

Rearranging slightly, we get
$$h_{n+1}=h_n+h_{n-1}$$
and
$$g_{n+1}=g_n+g_{n-1}.$$

Of course, we can find just by computing the first few terms that $h_1=h_2=1$, $g_1=1$, and $g_2=2$. However, this is simply the recursion formula for the fibonacci numbers! Thus, we know $h_n=F_n$ and $g_n=F_{n+1}$ (where $F_n$ is the $n$th fibonacci number). Therefore,
$$b_n=\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}.$$

At this point, there are many ways to show that the limit exists (And also show why you got the limit of $\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.).

Comment: I'm concerned by the conclusion that $h_{n+1} = g_n$ and $g_{n+1} = h_n + g_n$. Since rational numbers definitely do not correspond uniquely to ratios of integers, I think you're better off, logically, defining your system of difference equations in this way, with initial conditions, and showing $h_n/g_n$ satisfies the original recurrence.

Comment: However, since we're only concerened with the limit of the sequence, it doesn't actually matter wether the fraction is in most simplified form or not, does it? Most simplified form has no bearing on limits.

Comment: I would argue that your definition of $g_n$ and $h_n$ are poorly-defined. Even if you assumed $g_n$ and $h_n$ to be *one* of the sequences such that $b_n = h_n / g_n$, you cannot necessarily conclude from$$\frac{h_{n+1}}{g_{n+1}} = \frac{g_n}{h_n + g_n}$$that $h_{n+1} = g_n$ and $g_{n+1} = h_n + g_n$. Instead, you could only conclude that these equations were ratios (and not even constant ratios with respect to $n$). I think the idea is good, but you'd need to define $h_n$ and $g_n$ first, and show their ratio satisfies the original recursion.

Comment: Edited to reflect a tighter definition.